# upload file outside the root folder?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am confuse how to upload file outside the www root file. Here, the www root file is in the C drive. But I want to upload the file in the Z drive of the server. I have following php script to upload file. Here, I have uploaded file in www/uploadApps/file but I have to upload file in the another folder that is outside the www root folder and which is in another drive.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "file/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Do you use share hosting?or Dedicate Server?

Comment: I have my own server. Here, the EasyPHP 5 is installed in C drive of window server and I want to upload the file in folder of the z drive

Answer (score 2):

instead of `"file/"`, use an absolute path of where you want to file to be copied to.

for instance:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "Z:/somefolder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: @ShresthaSunil does the path you are trying to copy it to exist? do you have permissions to write to it? what do you mean by "not working"? is there an error?

Comment: Thanks it was working. I have put Capital letter Z in path  instead of small letter z.. Thanks again

Comment: how can I allow permissions to upload file in z of window server. I have PHP installed and MS IIS 7 installed in c drive. it shows following error:                                                                  Warning: move_uploaded_file(file/N_Wleo.wav) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ivr_admin\upload.php on line 163

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\PHP\uploadtemp\php816B.tmp' to 'file/N_Wleo.wav' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ivr_admin\upload.php on line 163

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path to point exactly where you want to store/retrieve the file from.

```
//Relative paths
$filePath = "file/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filePath = "/file/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

//Absolute paths
$filePath = "C:/www/uploadApps/file/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filePath = "Z:/file/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```